# Converting Decimal to less accurate Integer as a String

Tags: c#, formatting

Because some people apparently think that gigabytes as a decimal is a good way to accurately store available storage space I now have the following code to convert it into a byte representation:

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(someDecimal * 1024 * 1024)));
```

Now while this works (as-in returns the expected result), it's not exactly elegant.

Is there a more elegant way to do this kind of conversion? (The floor is necessary).

Comment: 1024^2 is for Megabytes, not Gigabytes.

Comment: This will give you the kilo-byte representation if `someDecimal` really contains GB.

Comment: You guys are right about the kilobyte thing. Thanks. Don't sleep while coding I guess.

Rik: Because rounding up (Which I understand Convert.ToInt64 does) could have really bad side effects, so erring on the side of caution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use this:

```
var result = ((Int64)(someDecimal * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)).ToString();
```

Of course, that should be encapsulated in some helper method. you don't want that sprinkled throughout your code.

Comment: You might want to use a `long` though

Comment: Because I wasn't sure whether explicit casting would round up or truncate? Also didn't know Math.Pow, or whether mulitplying by a constant would have significant performance gain?

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @Fuex: That edit is not valid. I posted something else! You didn't improve the code, you made it potentially slow. Never ever make such changes in an edit!

Comment: @MikkelLøkke: I wouldn't use Math.Pow for this task as it is potentially slower. I would use a constant, either inline as in my example or declared in some constant holder class.

Comment: @Daniel I'm sorry, I didn't want to make this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(someDecimal * Math.Pow(1024,3) - 0.5m).ToString("F0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving this line to a separate method (say, `gigabytesToBytes(someDecimal)`). This will make your intention clearer, and if you find bugs - like those spotted in the comments - you could fix them in one place.

Comment: Thanks, I already have, although I admit your suggestion for method name is better than the "whatTheHellIsWrongWithYou(someDecimal)" that I have now. :)